# i am getting an error while installing pycrypto in windos 10 in visual studio code

Tags: python, pycrypto

I got this error while installing pycrypto in visual studio code. I tried previous answers it didn't work for me

```
    Building wheel for pycrypto (setup.py) ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
    command: 'c:\users\uaahacker\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\uaahacker\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-703l_7f_\\pycrypto_4e1a5a16405a462790fc020871778555\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\uaahacker\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-703l_7f_\\pycrypto_4e1a5a16405a462790fc020871778555\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\uaahacker\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-gjdeek8y'
        cwd: C:\Users\uaahacker\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-703l_7f_\pycrypto_4e1a5a16405a462790fc020871778555\
    Complete output (153 lines):
    running bdist_wheel
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto
    copying lib\Crypto\pct_warnings.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto
    copying lib\Crypto\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\hashalgo.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\HMAC.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\MD2.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\MD4.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\MD5.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\RIPEMD.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA224.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA256.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA384.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA512.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Hash
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\AES.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\ARC2.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\ARC4.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\blockalgo.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\Blowfish.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\CAST.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\DES.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\DES3.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\PKCS1_OAEP.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\PKCS1_v1_5.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\XOR.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Cipher
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\asn1.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\Counter.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\number.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\py3compat.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\randpool.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\RFC1751.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\winrandom.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\_number_new.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Util
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Random
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\random.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Random
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\_UserFriendlyRNG.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Random
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Random
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Random\Fortuna
copying lib\Crypto\Random\Fortuna\FortunaAccumulator.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Random\Fortuna
copying lib\Crypto\Random\Fortuna\FortunaGenerator.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Random\Fortuna
copying lib\Crypto\Random\Fortuna\SHAd256.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Random\Fortuna
copying lib\Crypto\Random\Fortuna\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Random\Fortuna
creating build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Random\OSRNG
copying lib\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\fallback.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\nt.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\posix.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\rng_base.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Random\OSRNG
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\st_common.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\common.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_AES.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_ARC2.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_ARC4.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_Blowfish.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_CAST.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_DES.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_DES3.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_pkcs1_15.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_pkcs1_oaep.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_XOR.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\common.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_HMAC.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_MD2.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_MD4.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_MD5.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_RIPEMD.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA224.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA256.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA384.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA512.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\test_AllOrNothing.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\test_chaffing.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\test_KDF.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\test_rfc1751.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\test_DSA.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\test_ElGamal.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\test_importKey.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\test_RSA.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Random
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\test_random.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Random
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\test_rpoolcompat.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Random
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\test__UserFriendlyRNG.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Random
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Random
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna\test_FortunaAccumulator.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna        
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna\test_FortunaGenerator.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna\test_SHAd256.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_fallback.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_generic.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_nt.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_posix.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_winrandom.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\test_asn1.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\test_Counter.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\test_number.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\test_winrandom.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature\test_pkcs1_15.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature\test_pkcs1_pss.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\Protocol\AllOrNothing.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\Protocol\Chaffing.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\Protocol\KDF.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\Protocol\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Protocol
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\DSA.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\ElGamal.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\pubkey.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\RSA.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\_DSA.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\_RSA.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\_slowmath.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\PublicKey
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Signature
    copying lib\Crypto\Signature\PKCS1_PSS.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Signature
    copying lib\Crypto\Signature\PKCS1_v1_5.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Signature
    copying lib\Crypto\Signature\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Signature
    Skipping optional fixer: buffer
    Skipping optional fixer: idioms
    Skipping optional fixer: set_literal
    Skipping optional fixer: ws_comma
    running build_ext
    warning: GMP or MPIR library not found; Not building Crypto.PublicKey._fastmath.
    building 'Crypto.Random.OSRNG.winrandom' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
    ----------------------------------------
    ERROR: Failed building wheel for pycrypto
    Running setup.py clean for pycrypto
Failed to build pycrypto
Installing collected packages: pycrypto
    Running setup.py install for pycrypto ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
        command: 'c:\users\uaahacker\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\uaahacker\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-703l_7f_\\pycrypto_4e1a5a16405a462790fc020871778555\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\uaahacker\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-703l_7f_\\pycrypto_4e1a5a16405a462790fc020871778555\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\uaahacker\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-9k1tmf02\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\uaahacker\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\Include\pycrypto'
            cwd: C:\Users\uaahacker\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-703l_7f_\pycrypto_4e1a5a16405a462790fc020871778555\
    Complete output (153 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto
    copying lib\Crypto\pct_warnings.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto
    copying lib\Crypto\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\hashalgo.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\HMAC.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\MD2.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\MD4.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\MD5.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\RIPEMD.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA224.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA256.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA384.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA512.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\Hash\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Hash
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\AES.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\ARC2.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\ARC4.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\blockalgo.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\Blowfish.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\CAST.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\DES.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\DES3.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\PKCS1_OAEP.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\PKCS1_v1_5.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\XOR.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Cipher
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\asn1.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\Counter.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\number.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\py3compat.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\randpool.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\RFC1751.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\winrandom.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\_number_new.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\Util\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Util
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Random
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\random.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Random
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\_UserFriendlyRNG.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Random
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Random
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Random\Fortuna
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\Fortuna\FortunaAccumulator.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Random\Fortuna
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\Fortuna\FortunaGenerator.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Random\Fortuna
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\Fortuna\SHAd256.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Random\Fortuna
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\Fortuna\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Random\Fortuna
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\fallback.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\nt.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\posix.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\rng_base.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Random\OSRNG
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\st_common.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\common.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_AES.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_ARC2.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_ARC4.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_Blowfish.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_CAST.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_DES.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_DES3.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_pkcs1_15.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_pkcs1_oaep.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_XOR.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\common.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_HMAC.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_MD2.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_MD4.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_MD5.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_RIPEMD.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA224.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA256.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA384.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA512.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\test_AllOrNothing.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\test_chaffing.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\test_KDF.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\test_rfc1751.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\test_DSA.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\test_ElGamal.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\test_importKey.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\test_RSA.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Random
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\test_random.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Random
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\test_rpoolcompat.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Random
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\test__UserFriendlyRNG.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Random
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Random
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna\test_FortunaAccumulator.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna      
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna\test_FortunaGenerator.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna        
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna\test_SHAd256.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_fallback.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_generic.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_nt.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_posix.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_winrandom.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\test_asn1.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\test_Counter.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\test_number.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\test_winrandom.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature\test_pkcs1_15.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature\test_pkcs1_pss.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\Protocol\AllOrNothing.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\Protocol\Chaffing.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\Protocol\KDF.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Protocol
    copying lib\Crypto\Protocol\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Protocol
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\DSA.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\ElGamal.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\pubkey.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\RSA.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\_DSA.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\_RSA.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\_slowmath.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\PublicKey
    copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\PublicKey
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Signature
    copying lib\Crypto\Signature\PKCS1_PSS.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Signature
    copying lib\Crypto\Signature\PKCS1_v1_5.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Signature
    copying lib\Crypto\Signature\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Signature
    Skipping optional fixer: buffer
    Skipping optional fixer: idioms
    Skipping optional fixer: set_literal
    Skipping optional fixer: ws_comma
    running build_ext
    warning: GMP or MPIR library not found; Not building Crypto.PublicKey._fastmath.
    building 'Crypto.Random.OSRNG.winrandom' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\uaahacker\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\uaahacker\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-703l_7f_\\pycrypto_4e1a5a16405a462790fc020871778555\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\uaahacker\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-703l_7f_\\pycrypto_4e1a5a16405a462790fc020871778555\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', 
'"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\uaahacker\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-9k1tmf02\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\uaahacker\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\Include\pycrypto' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try in a admin shell (on windows cmd):

```
pip install pycrypto
```

And also what did you try already?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and pip requires Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater.

But if you are using anaconda framework, I strongly recommend if you are using Windows OS, "conda" command installs it.

Open CMD with admin privileges.

```
conda install pycrypto
```